# rem unit doesn't take affect according to mobile device's font-size on android

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, accessibility

Can anyone help me to understand why rem unit doesn't scale according to mobile device's font-size only on Android?

I already set my font-size using `rem` unit based. And in IOS device also working expectedly.
I have tried surf around google and GPT/Gemini but doesn't seem find the exact explanation.
I also attach the video below for better explanation

- web example to test: https://codepen.io/devinekadeni/pen/abMrYdP
- mobile browser (both Android/IOS): Chrome
- device emulator android: Pixel 7 Pro API 33
- device emulator IOS: Iphone 14 Pro IOS 16.2

1. Video IOS device: https://jmp.sh/eg3fSgsR
2. Video Android device: https://jmp.sh/jHaXJEIC

I also already tried on real device but the result is still the same: IOS works, android not.

Any help or even confirming that you also experiencing this would be appreciated.